# How can I match light levels in a composite / panorama astronomy photo?

Tags: post-processing, astrophotography, panorama, sun

I have made a mosaique of the sun, but all pictures have different light levels. I was wondering how to match these colors to be the same everywhere.

So basically I need all the pink to be the same shade, so that it will look like one picture.

[image]

Comment: I'm just curious, but if all the partial photos came from the same camera, can't you then put them each on its own layer and fiddle with the exposure values separately on each layer until they all blend nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it by setting it to grayscale and doing levels then (a lot easier) and afterwards healing whats left with the heal brush.

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FilIK.jpg[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you want to attempt something like this with a fixed set of camera settings and lots of overlap so you can avoid using any vignetted portion.  To try and do it manually, you will need to account for white balance, black point, white point, gamma and any vignettes (such as on the lower center piece).  If you don't have a known gradient for the vignette, it will be pretty time consuming to do.

Your best bet may actually be to overlap the layers and use an eraser brush with soft edges to help blend them together.  You'll still have some variation, but it should make it less noticeable as the variations shift.  If you don't have enough overlap, this technique won't really work either though.

Comment: I have enough overlap to get rid of most the vignetting (also the lower corner is now gone) but they still all are different shades of pink. Especially the center parts. Isn't there some way to match the colors?

Comment: @Coolcrab - it isn't just matching a fixed color though, it's matching the darkest parts to the darkest parts, the brightest parts to the brightest parts and the response curve between darkest and brightest.  It's also matching the white balance of the image so that color hue and tint match.  Color matching is hard to do well.  Hue and brightness adjustments coupled with smooth blending can probably get an acceptable result though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a professional stitching software that does this, or use some freeware, e.g. Panotools. Those automatically do the required steps (maybe after some manual help).

An alternative is to go to L*a*b, pick representative points on the perimeter of the sun, and use curves to manually arrive at the same luminance, "a" and "b" values. Then pick a L*a*b value for the center, and use further curving to adjust that point on each image, meanwhile leaving the previously set curve points on each layer untouched. You will at least have two points matching on each layer. You will still have to manually mess a bit with curves' curvature, but two points on each curve is a good start. You will probably need one more. You can use the black point as well, and use the symmetry point of the composite image abundantly.

And BTW: you will have to disconnect curves for L, "a" and "b" for each layer, at the beginning.